# How to do Couple and Decouple a div from parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div - myCcontainer and I have a child div - div2.
when I moved parent div the child div should occupy the same position and the parent should be moved to somewhere. 
How can I do this with JavaScript ?

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <style type="text/css">


            .cpdiv{
                    background-color: yellow;
                    width:150px;
                    height:150px;
                        border: 2px solid black;
            }
            #myContainer {
              width: 500px;
              height: 500px;
              position: relative;
              border: 2px solid #222333;
            }
            #container {
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="container" >
                <div id="myContainer" >
                    <div >
                        <button id="btn3"  onclick="myMove()">Move</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cpdiv" id="div2">
                        <label>hai</label>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <script>
            function myMove() {
              var elem = document.getElementById("myContainer");
              document.getElementById("div2").style.position = "fixed";
              var pos = 0;
              var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
              function frame() {
                if (pos == 150) {
                  clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                  pos++;
                  elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
                  elem.style.left = pos + 'px';

                }
              }
            }
            </script>   
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Changed your css a bit:

```
            .cpdiv{
                background-color: yellow;
                width:150px;
                height:150px;
                border: 2px solid black;
                top: 20px;
                left:20px;
        }
```